# What is the difference between two below definitions for lambda?

Tags: python

I saw two models for lambda and could not use them instead of them. You suppose:

```
languages = ["HTML", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]
print max(lambda x:x=="Python", languages)
```

You can see it is started with lambda then x:x and at the end the name of list(y). Suppose below:

```
languages = ["HTML", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]
print max(languages,key=lambda x:x=="Python" )
```

I found that in an example. In this one a parameter is equal with lambda, the name of list is in the beginning and it is different all in all from the first one. Are there two different definitions?
Thanks

Comment: `lambda x:x=="Python"` and `lambda student: student.score` - exact same syntax for the lambda function. The two cases you posted are different because `map` and `filter` are different functions.

Comment: The `x` and `student` are just the names of the parameters in each case.  They are different because we choose names that are descriptive - although I doubt `x` is descriptive unless a graph is being plotted.  Did you try both?  Did it make any difference?  Copying someone else's code is not a good way to learn.  Try reading http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

**Filter** takes a **function** and an **iterable** (list) 
[i.e. `filter(function, iterable)`]

You are passing the lambda (`lambda x:x=="Python"`) as the first argument here.

**Max** takes an **iterable** and (in this case) a single argument 'key' **function**
[i.e. `max(iterable[, key])`]

You are passing the lambda (`lambda student: student.score`) as the second, named, key argument.

Both your lambdas are the same lambda syntax. Perhaps you are confused because the second one uses the keyword argument (`key=...`) to pass the lambda to the function?

Answer (score 0):

I answer. These are old versions and cannot be acceptable for paython 3 to above. It can be usable as below:

```
squares=[x**2 for x in range(1,11)]
c=max(filter(lambda x: x>=30 and x<=70,squares))
print (squares)

print (c)
```

or

```
f=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(list(filter(lambda x:x%2==0,f)))
print(max(filter(lambda x:x%2==0,f)))
```

Your knowledge is old.